# Knex chaining table creation in migrations

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I have the following migration code:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table){
        table.increments();
        table.string('email', 100).unique().notNullable();
        table.string('password').notNullable();
      })
      .createTable('posts', function(table){
        table.increments();
        table.string('title').notNullable();
        table.string('content').notNullable();
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());

        table.int('userId').notNullable().references('id').inTable('users');
      })
      .createTable('comments', function(table){
        table.increments();
        table.string('content').notNullable();
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        
        table.int('userId').notNullable().references('id').inTable('users');
        table.int('postId').notNullable().references('id').inTable('posts');
      })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users')
  .dropTable('posts')
  .dropTable('comments');
};
```

Its generating the following error:

```
migration failed with error: create table "posts" ("id" serial primary key, "title" varchar(255) not null, "content" varchar(255) not null, "created_at" timestamptz default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "userId" undefined not null) - type "undefined" does not exist
```

It seems to have a hard time connecting the users and posts table, but I'm not sure as to why.

Comment: I copied it as is, and it worked fine? Not sure if that is a thing, but you might want to change the `down` function to drop in the opposite order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Here, instead of int

```
    table.int('userId').notNullable().references('id').inTable('users');
```

It should have been integer.

```
    table.integer('userId').notNullable().references('id').inTable('users');
```